# How would I incorporate more than one for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I've recently started learning python and was wondering if I could get some assistance in developing an array with more than one *for* loops.

```
''' Postcondition: A 5x5 array as follows is on the monitor:
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
'''

for row_index in range(5):
    row = ''
    for col_index in range(5):
        row += ' - '
    print(row)
```

Now I'm trying to produce something similar, but this time with an additional loop.

```
'''Postcondition: A 5x5 array as follows is on the monitor:
! - - - -
- ! - - -
- - ! - -
- - - ! -
- - - - !
'''
```

How would I go about adding an additional *for* loop to get this outcome?

Comment: Check when `col_index` is equal to `row_index` and then add ! instead of -

Comment: Notably, you can generate this as a nested list comp. `'\n'.join([' '.join(['!' if x==y else '-' for x in range(5)]) for y in range(5)])`

Answer (score 0):

You **do not need an extra for loop**!

Just check for the condition where `row_index == col_index` and add `!` to the string if so.

```
for row_index in range(5):
    row = ''
    for col_index in range(5):
        if row_index == col_index :
              row+= '!'
        else :
              row += ' - '
    print(row)
```